# Использование new(this)

Tags: c++

Читаю [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/faq). В разделе [Constructors](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors) натыкаюсь такое высказывание:

> BTW do NOT try to achieve this via placement new. Some people think
>   they can say new(this) Foo(x, int(x)+7) within the body of
>   Foo::Foo(char). However that is bad, bad, bad. Please don’t write me
>   and tell me that it seems to work on your particular version of your
>   particular compiler; it’s bad

Речь идет о том, то что так делать категорически нельзя:

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(char x){
        new (this) Foo(x, int(x)+7); 
    }
    Foo(char x, int y){
        //...
    }
};
```

Может кто-нибудь более подробно объяснить чем грозит такой трюк?

**UPD:** Подозреваю что в данном примере все будет нормально, и проблемы начнутся при наследовании, динамическом выделении ресурсов и т.п.

Comment: Ну, там же должно быть разъяснение этого эмоционального автора.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, *Constructors do a bunch of little magical things behind the scenes, but that bad technique steps on those partially constructed bits. Just say no.*

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мне оно, если честно, не особо помогло:)

Comment: В общем случае проблема с таким кодом состоит в том, что когда выполняется тело конструктора, то объект и его подобъекты уже сконструированы. Вызывая по второму разу конструктор, деструкторы для созданных объектов не вызываются, что ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ideone.com/gkgi7S:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()  { ptr = new int[100]; cout << "alloc mem at " << ptr << endl; }
    ~Base() { delete [] ptr; cout << "free mem at " << ptr << endl; }
    int * ptr;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}
    Derived(int x)
    {
        new(this) Derived(x,0);
    }
    int x, y;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Derived d(5);
}
```

Вывод:

```
alloc mem at 0070EA58
alloc mem at 0070FFE8
free mem at 0070FFE8
```

Такого примера достаточно?...

Можно и без наследования - суть не меняется:

```
class Derived
{
public:
    Derived(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}
    Derived(int x)
    {
        new(this) Derived(x,0);
    }
    int x, y;
    Base b;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Что пишет <strike>наместник бога на Земле</strike> Страуструп: [линк](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#placement-delete)

Пример использования:

```
/*1*/ char *pBuf  = new char[sizeof(string)]; 
/*2*/ string *p = new (pBuf) string("hi");    
/*3*/ string *q = new string("hi");
```

В первой строке мы выделяем память, во-второй - мы строим объект на *уже выделенном* участке памяти. Пример банальный, но суть Вы уловите: мы строим объект на заранее выделенном участке памяти и можем быть уверены в том, что не произойдет отказа в выделении памяти - ведь она уже выделенна в нужном "объеме", если так можно выразится. Реальный пример - какие-то критические секции, для которых важно быстродействие, отсутствие исключений и т.п.

Оператор *размещения*, например:

```
const SomeoneClass& SomeoneClass::operator=( const SomeoneClass& other) {
   if ( this != &other ) {
      this->~SomeoneClass();
      new (this) SomeoneClass(other);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

*Ну и обратите внимание что пишет Страуструп оо освобождении памяти в таких случаях.*